# Laravel Eloquent Model - can't access database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to write a simple site that can write and read of a simple mysql database, using Laravel, but I've run into a full stop as Laravel doesn't seem to be recognising my model. Either that or I am doing something wrong.

My model:

```
class Submission extends Eloquent
{
    public static $timestamps = true;
    protected $fillable = array('location', 'twitter', 'instagram', 'website');
}
```

My form:

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
{{ Input::old('twitter') }} <br />
{{ Input::old('instagram') }} <br />
{{ Input::old('website') }} <br />
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/submission', 'files' => true)) }}
    <div class="form-group"> 
        {{ Form::label('twitter', 'Twitter') }}
        {{ Form::text('twitter', '', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"> 
        {{ Form::label('instagram', 'Instagram') }}
        {{ Form::text('instagram', '', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"> 
        {{ Form::label('website', 'Website') }}
        {{ Form::text('website', '', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
    </div>
    {{ Form::button('Submit image', array('class' => 'btn btn-success', 'type' => 'submit')) }}
    <input type="hidden" name="post" value="yes">
{{ Form::close() }}
@stop
```

My controller:

```
public function postView()
    {
        $submission = new Submission;
        $submission->twitter = Input::get('twitter');
        $submission->instagram = Input::get('instagram');
        $submission->website = Input::get('website');

        $submission->save();

        return Redirect::to('submission')->withInput();
    }
```

My database looks like: `id location twitter instagram website created_at updated_at`

I know that my database config is correct as I can retrieve information using `DB::table('submissions')->get();` so from what I can tell it's Laravel that's not recognising my model?

**EDIT:**
Turns out that changing `public static $timestamps = true;` to `public $timestamps = true;` fixed it.

Comment: What's the exact file name of your model? Also, when you say its not recognising it, are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Checked the logs and turned out that just editing $timestamps to "public $timestamps = true" fixed it all.

Comment: well at least its fixed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this works :

> DB::table('submissions')->get();

as it should return everything in the table. If it works then Eloquent can't find your table you can try to put that in your model:

> protected $table = 'submissions';

It will define explicitly the table name in the model, even if it seems correct in your case

Otherwise you need to tell what exactly laravel answers when you made a request.

- Do you have an error message in your browser ?
- Do you have an error message in your log file (check the app/storage/logs folder)
- Is your database configuration ok ? (app/config/database.php)
- Did you create the table using a laravel migration ?

Hope it helps

Comment: I don't know why I hadn't checked the logs before. Silly me. It turns out that Laravel didn't like $timestamps to be static. Just doing "public $timestamps = true" fixed it all. Thanks for your help :-)